# Предзагрузка картинки для background

Tags: jquery, css

Добрый день, пишу свой прелодер на сайт, на блок добавлена background-image *.svg и установлен background-color, однако иногда интернет подлагивает , bg-image грузит дольше чем цвет фона, хотелось бы узнать как сделать предзагрузку изображения *.svg, а затем bg-image дать значение изображения

Comment: а как в итоге должно выглядеть ? сначала белый фон, на нем текст, а потом фон с картинкой ?

Comment: а зачем вообще цвет беку, если там будет картинка?

Comment: @Jean-Claude *.svg - это иконка поверх фона залитого цветом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для chrome браузеров можно воспользоваться тем, что `<link rel='preload'>` генерирует событие load:

```js
document.getElementById('bgpreload').addEventListener('load', () =>
  document.body.classList.add('bgLoaded')
);
```

```css
body.bgLoaded {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link id="bgpreload" rel="preload" as="image" href="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
```

Если картинка кэшируема, то можно так:

```js
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = function() {
  document.body.className += ' bgLoaded';
}
img.src = 'https://placeimg.com/400/200/any';
```

```css
body.bgLoaded {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/400/200/any");
  background-color: red;
}
```